# 2 Decimal Places in a <span> element in Angular

Tags: angularjs, regex

In my angular app, I have a span element where I need to display some values from service response.

Currently it is showing like

```
> value = 20.00000000000
```

whereas I want to display in the following manner

```
> value = 20.00
```

The problem is I have to display the value in a `<span>` element. I want to achieve it `without using regex`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using angular, you can do something like so: `<span>{{value | number:2}}</span>`. This should render your `value` parameter to 2 decimal places.